# Metodo append no funciona en lista simplemente enlazada

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, estructuras-de-datos

¿Alguien me puede explicar porqué mi método `append` no esta funcionando?

Soy nuevo en las estructuras de datos y estoy aprendiendo, se supone que este método agrega un elemento al final de la lista, pero al imprimir la lista solo se imprime un elemento.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class linkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last_node = self.head
        while last_node.next:
            last_node = last_node.next
        else:
            last_node = new_node

    def print_list(self):
        cur_node = self.head

        while cur_node.next != None:
            print(cur_node.data)
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        while cur_node.next is None:
            print(cur_node.data)
            break


lista = linkedList()
lista.append("b")
lista.append("c")
lista.print_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la última línea del método:

```
last_node = new_node
```

No tienes que "substituir" el último nodo por el nuevo, tienes que enlazar el nuevo con el último mediante el atributo `next`:

```
def append(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)

    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
        return

    last_node = self.head
    while last_node.next:
        last_node = last_node.next
    else:
        last_node.next = new_node
```

Es más, `last_node = new_node` ni siquiera substituye el nodo en la lista realmente, lo único que hace es reasignar a la variable local `last_node` una referencia al nodo nuevo.

Comment: gracias fjsevilla siempre respondes mis dudas, eres un genio